# Error: cannot execute binary file from dir

Tags: bash, shell-script, shell, source

I installed a community software which requires to run some bash scripts in particular directory. However, an error message showed up if I did so:

```
"ERROR: Command: 'source /usr/bin/bash && module list' failed with error '/bin/sh: line 0: source: /usr/bin/bash: cannot execute binary file' from dir '/home/xxx/example1'.
```

If I change the directory to `/usr/bin`, it works. The issue is I have to run the script in the directory of `example1`. I tried to add /usr/bin into PATH, but it didn't work. Any comments are appreciated. Thanks.

Update1:
here is the python script the software used to generate shell script:

```
def make_env_mach_specific_file(self, shell, case, output_dir=''):
        """Writes .env_mach_specific.sh or .env_mach_specific.csh

        Args:
        shell: string - 'sh' or 'csh'
        case: case object
        output_dir: string - path to output directory (if empty string, uses current directory)
        """
        module_system = self.get_module_system_type()
        sh_init_cmd = self.get_module_system_init_path(shell)
        sh_mod_cmd = self.get_module_system_cmd_path(shell)
        lines = ["# This file is for user convenience only and is not used by the model"]

        lines.append("# Changes to this file will be ignored and overwritten")
        lines.append("# Changes to the environment should be made in env_mach_specific.xml")
        lines.append("# Run ./case.setup --reset to regenerate this file")
        if sh_init_cmd:
            lines.append("source {}".format(sh_init_cmd))

        if "SOFTENV_ALIASES" in os.environ:
            lines.append("source $SOFTENV_ALIASES")
        if "SOFTENV_LOAD" in os.environ:
            lines.append("source $SOFTENV_LOAD")

        if self._unit_testing or self._standalone_configure:
            job = None
        else:
            job = case.get_primary_job()
        modules_to_load = self._get_modules_for_case(case, job=job)
        envs_to_set = self._get_envs_for_case(case, job=job)
        filename = ".env_mach_specific.{}".format(shell)
        if modules_to_load is not None:
            if module_system == "module":
                lines.extend(self._get_module_commands(modules_to_load, shell))
            else:
                for action, argument in modules_to_load:
                    lines.append("{} {} {}".format(sh_mod_cmd, action, "" if argument is None else argument))

        if envs_to_set is not None:
            for env_name, env_value in envs_to_set:
                if shell == "sh":
                    if env_name:
                        lines.append("export {}={}".format(env_name, env_value))
                    else:
                        lines.append("source {}".format(env_value))

                elif shell == "csh":
                    if env_name:
                        lines.append("setenv {} {}".format(env_name, env_value))
                    else:
                        lines.append("echo \"This case includes a shell source file {} which cannot be used from csh type shells\"".format(env_value))
                else:
                    expect(False, "Unknown shell type: '{}'".format(shell))

        with open(os.path.join(output_dir, filename), "w") as fd:
            fd.write("\n".join(lines))
```

Comment: I don't know what you are trying to do, but `source /usr/bin/bash` is just wrong. You cannot source a binary in a shell script. Are you absolutely sure that it works from `/usr/bin`? I ask this because it should not work there either. Can you add the shell script that requires this too the question (if it is not to long),?

Comment: Thanks for your reply. The software I am using is named CESM, a community software for earth system modeling. @Ljm Dullaart I attached the python script that is used to generate the shell script. It looks like the python script reads my shell and then prefix 'source'. As you said, source cannot be used for a binary file. I don't know why the script does this.

Comment: The script adds two source-statements to the file; both are taken from the bash-environment. What happens if you do `echo "SOFTENV_ALIASES=$SOFTENV_ALIASES; SOFTENV_LOAD=$SOFTENV_LOAD"` ?